# What is easiest way to retrieve one column's values using SubSonic (Column isn't primary)

Tags: mysql, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm using AcriveRecord in SubSonic 3.0.0.3 with MySql.
Is there some easy way to perform something like "SELECT `CustomerAddress` FROM `customers`" rather than .All() which performs "SELECT * FROM `customers`"? And how to get distinct values?

Answer (score 3):

```
var qry= from c in Customer.All()
         select new {
            c.CustomerAddress
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, Rob.
And thank you for SubSonic project ;)